# using Visual Studio Community with Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Can you use Visual Studio Community with Team Foundation Server Express?

Our development team is looking into low cost ways of developing applications and was wondering if this possible?  Were a team of 5.

Comment: which final alternative you choose?

Comment: ***Visual Studio 2017 Community*** supports TFS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes It can, however It still need installed on a server. You should use Visual Studio Online (cloud based TFS) which provides 5 users for free...
http://tfs.visualstudio.com

Comment: Servers aren't a problem.  So community can be used with TFS Express as long as its on a tin box or Virtual running Server 2012 or something? Have I got this right?

Comment: Yes, however VSO (TFS Online) is a better solution

Comment: Is this stil exist on the year? I cannot login since TFS merge with Azure DevOps Server

Answer (score 3):

Team Explorer connects Visual Studio to team projects. If you don’t need Visual Studio, but do want to connect to Team Services or TFS or get one or more Team Foundation add-ins, you can install the free Visual Studio Community.

Clients that connect to Team Services or TFS include Visual Studio Community.

As per the latest update. **Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2 is free for up to five users, replacing TFS Express**. Existing TFS Express users can run an upgrade to the Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2 and continue to use it free for up to five users. For the sixth user and beyond, CALs must be used. For more info you can check the Visual Studio licensing white paper.

Comment: Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2017 connects to Team Foundation Server 2017, Team Foundation Server 2015, Team Foundation Server 2013, Team Foundation Server 2012 and Team Foundation Server 2010 SP1.  ***Visual Studio 2017 Community*** not support TeamExplorer - TFS ?